# I can't download apps due to My Family and My Family isn't working

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, parental-control

At the moment, I can't download apps onto my phone. I'll be 18 next week, and my mom got me the new Nokia 920, but every time I try to download apps it says a parent needs to add me to My Family.

Every time I have tried getting onto My Family, it keeps telling me there is an error and to try again later. It's been 2 weeks since I got my phone and I still can't get onto My Family, or download apps!

Comment: Have you visited familysafety.live.com?

Comment: I need help to set my family at Nokia Lumia 820 ,I'm not using Nokia Lumia 920.

Answer (score 2):

Try talking to the xbox support guys via http://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us .  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

Your parent needs to be the one to go to My Family, not you. You can't set up My Family if your account is a child account. Here's the info and FAQ: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/my-family-on-the-windows-phone-website

Answer (score -1):

You have to go into your email account that is attached to the windows account and change your age to 21. I am having the same exact problems with my Lumia 920 and I turn 18 soon.

Comment: you can't, because otherwise child protection would be useless.